# Scss global variables across files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

This is in VS 2013 update 3. I declared the variables in `_variables.scss`:

```
$fontFamily: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
$shapeColor: #ACAEAA;
...
```

Then it is imported at the very beginning of my `main.scss` as below:

```
@import '_variables.scss';
@import '_base.scss'; // not able to use any variables declared in _variables.css
```

In `main.scss`, all the global variables work fine. However, none of the global variables works in _base.scss. VS refuses to compile them and they are marked as `Undeclared Variable`.
Is this a VS compiler issue or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you add the following to `_base.scss` and your intellisense should behave.

```
/// <reference path="_variables.scss" />
```

I have written a post on this if you need more info [Get intellisense in sass/less files in visual-studio](http://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/get-intellisense-in-sass-less-files-in-visual-studio)

Comment: The squiggly lines are gone and intellisense works. However, it still shows `_base.scss` compilation failed: The service failed to respond to this request. Possible cause: Syntax Error!

Comment: The CSS actually works but the compilation error message could be misleading. Why is it working but still showing error messages?

Comment: I sometimes get this when I save in a partial file (one prefixed with `_`).  But if you save `main.scss` it will compile successfully.  Not sure why it does this, maybe a bug in Web Essentials.

Comment: Works great! If the referenced file is inside a folder, make sure you map the correct path _directly from the referencing file_. In our company, we have `@import "partials/helpers/_variables`  and `@import "partials/_settings` in "application.scss", so in _settings.scss we need `/// <reference path="helpers/_variables.scss" />`.

Comment: Do you have to do this to *every* file individually?

Comment: Like @JMK, I'm wondering if there's a more centralized way to write this in one spot and have it apply to every file? See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59329833/422845