# How can you use Reference Paths for multiple SCSS Files in Visual Studio, to utilize Intellisense, without having to add it to every file?

Tags: visual-studio, sass, intellisense, visual-studio-2019, tooling

In Visual Studio you can include reference paths within your SASS/SCSS files using the following syntax within a .scss file:

```
/// <reference path="vars.scss" />
```

This is very helpful for providing intellisense for SASS variables and mixins. Right now I have to add a reference path manually to every single SASS file to get this benefit.

Is there a way to define "global" Reference Paths for your sass files, where you could define a path once, so that it is available in ALL sass files going forward?

I'm running into an issue where I want to reference multiple SASS files from various packages, but do not want to have to add multiple reference paths to every single SASS file.

On another note: does someone know where there is documentation on `<reference path="">` for visual studio?

Comment: Hi, please check if [this document](https://madskristensen.net/blog/the-story-behind-_referencesjs) helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm running into an issue where I want to reference multiple SASS
>   files from various packages, but do want to have to add multiple
>   reference paths to every single SASS file.

I think you can just define a global file named `_references.scss` and then put all referenced scss files into it. This file must be located in the folder named `Css` which you at the root of your project.

Then add like these into `_references.scss`

```
/// <reference path="vars.scss" />
/// <reference path="content.scss />
/// <reference path="background.scss" />
```

When you want to use it, just reference the unique global  file `_reference.scss`.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: This is a better solution than I have, but not what I am hoping to achieve, which would be to avoid having to reference `_references.scss` in EVERY single SCSS file. Isn't there a global way to reference these like adding namespaces in web.configs?

Comment: very nice setup indeed!